# xindy : how to add new letters and lettergroups to the alphabet?

Tags: indexing, xindy

How to define a style file that adds a couple of extra letters to the latin alphabet, and the corresponding lettergroups?

I'm using the `index` package, and compiling the `.idx` files with `texindy` like this:

```
texindy -o book.main.ind -L english -M lang/english/utf8 -M style1 book.main.idx
```

I'm working on an index that has words from the Pāḷi language, such as ānāpānasati, saṃsāra, ñāṇavimutti.

The `\index` commands give these word using the TeX accents, so in the text the above words would be indexed with:

```
\index[general]{\=an\=ap\=anasati}
\index[general]{sa\d{m}s\=ara}
\index[general]{\~n\=a\d{n}avimutti}
```

I tried adding the letter groups, but the ā, ñ, etc. letters don't begin new groups, they are just included under the latin letters a, n, etc.

```lisp
(define-letter-group "ā" :after "a" :before "b")
(define-letter-group "ñ" :after "n" :before "o")

(merge-rule "\=a" "ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\={a}" "ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\d{m}" "ṃ" :string)
(merge-rule "\d {m}" "ṃ" :string)
(merge-rule "\~n" "ñ" :string)
(merge-rule "\~ n" "ñ" :string)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Longer post

I have prepared two versions for Pāḷi language to be used by [`xindy`](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/): general one (English sorting rules plus several new letters and a portion of sorting rules from Pāḷi) and a minimal one (for Pāḷi language only).

I am running examples with `lualatex`, those work with `xelatex` too. The engines use Latin Modern for typesetting. Several phonetic letters weren't rendered correctly, so I used [Code2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) font. If you want to run `pdflatex`, please, consider to use [`iec2utf`](https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf), that's a Lua script programmed by michal-h21.

I have used several resources (listed below) to get Pāḷi words as test cases. In case I misspelled some of them, I am sorry for that.

- This question.
- http://urbandharma.org/pdf/palidict.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali
- http://www.budsas.org/ebud/dict-pe/
- http://www.pratyeka.org/narada/
- http://www.nibbanam.com/pali_language_tools.html, esp. [this file](http://www.nibbanam.com/pswl.zip)

---

> To 1. General version (Sorting rules of some Western languages plus Pāḷi)

I wanted to make sure that not only letters will be added but also that Pāḷi words will be sorted properly. I have extracted new letters from http://www.omniglot.com/writing/pali.htm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali. Moreover, I've also kept in mind this file http://pratyeka.org/narada/pali_alphabets.pdf and I've added several phonetic symbols to the alphabet as an experiment if Xindy can handle that (it can).

I have downloaded and installed [Code2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) font to make sure that all letters, especially those uncommon ones, will be displayed correctly.

I enclose a list of 36 letter groups:

```
% run: lualatex or xelatex typeset-paligeneral.tex
% Alphabet has 36 elements.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newenvironment{alphabet}{\begin{tabular}{*{16}{l}}}{\end{tabular}}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2in}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm
\setmainfont{Code2000}

\begin{document}
\section{Paligeneral}
\subsection{Alphabet}
\begin{alphabet}
a\,A & á\,Á & à\,À & ă\,Ă & â\,Â & ã\,Ã & ä\,Ä & ą\,Ą & å\,Å & æ\,Æ & ǽ\,Ǽ\\
ā\,Ā\\
b\,B\\
c\,C & ć\,Ć & ĉ\,Ĉ & ç\,Ç & č\,Č\\
d\,D & ð\,ð & đ\,đ & ď\,Ď\\
ḍ\,Ḍ & ɖ\,Ɖ\\
e\,E & é\,É & è\,È & ě\,Ě & ê\,Ê & ë\,Ë & ę\,Ę & þ\,Þ\\
f\,F\\
g\,G & ĝ\,Ĝ & ğ\,Ğ\\
h\,H & ĥ\,Ĥ & ı\,I\\
i\,I & í\,Í & ì\,Ì & î\,Î & ï\,Ï\\
ī\,Ī\\
j\,J & ĵ\,Ĵ\\
k\,K\\
l\,L & ĺ\,Ĺ & ł\,Ł & ľ\,Ľ\\
ḷ\,Ḷ & ɭ\,ɭ\\
m\,M\\
ṃ\,Ṃ & ŋ\,Ŋ & ɱ\,ɱ\\
n\,N & ń\,Ń & ň\,Ň\\
ṅ\,Ṅ & ɲ\,Ɲ\\
ñ\,Ñ\\
ṇ\,Ṇ & ɳ\,ɳ\\
o\,O & ó\,Ó & ő\,Ő & ò\,Ò & ö\,Ö & ø\,Ø & ǿ\,Ǿ & ô\,Ô & õ\,Õ & œ\,Œ\\
p\,P\\
q\,Q\\
r\,R & ŕ\,Ŕ & ř\,Ř\\
s\,S & ś\,Ś & ŝ\,Ŝ & ş\,Ş & š\,Š\\
t\,T & ť\,Ť\\
ṭ\,Ṭ & ʈ\,Ʈ\\
u\,U & ú\,Ú & ù\,Ù & ŭ\,Ŭ & ů\,Ů & û\,Û & ü\,Ü & ű\,Ű\\
ū\,Ū\\
v\,V\\
w\,W\\
x\,X\\
y\,Y & ý\,Ý & ÿ\,Ÿ\\
z\,Z & ź\,Ź & ż\,Ż & ž\,Ž
\end{alphabet}

\subsection{Ligatures}
\begin{flushleft}
`ß' is sorted like `s\,s', but \emph{after} it in otherwise equal words.
\end{flushleft}

\subsection{Upper-/lowercase words}
Capitalized or uppercase words are sorted \emph{before} otherwise equal lowercase words.

\subsection{Special characters}
The order of special characters and letters is:
\begin{flushleft}
?\hspace{4mm}!\hspace{4mm}.\hspace{4mm}letters\hspace{4mm}-\hspace{4mm}'
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, general version, list of letters]

> Usage

Please download these two files to your working directory:

```
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/utf8.pl-paligeneral.in.xdy  
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/utf8.pl-paligeneral.in-test.xdy
```

We run these three lines on the first example (`mal-paligeneral.tex`):

```
lualatex mal-paligeneral.tex
xindy -M texindy -M utf8.pl-paligeneral.in-test -M bonus mal-paligeneral.idx
lualatex mal-paligeneral.tex
```

If you wish to check out the vector versions, please download:

```
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/typeset-paligeneral.pdf
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/mal-paligeneral.pdf
```

This is the content of the TeX file, I will enclose a preview of it at the end of this post so we can compare those two versions.

```
% run: lualatex or xelatex mal-paligeneral.tex
% uncomment line 9 or 10, respectively
%
%lualatex mal-paligeneral.tex
%xindy -M texindy -M utf8.pl-paligeneral.in-test -M bonus mal-paligeneral.idx
%lualatex mal-paligeneral.tex
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra} % for lualatex engine
%\usepackage{xltxtra} % for xelatex engine
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bonus.xdy}
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n  \textbf{" :close-head "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Regular text.
\index{pāḷi}
\index{ānāpānasati}
\index{saṃsāra}
\index{ñāṇavimutti}
% Pali Buddhist Dictionary
\index{insight}
\index{paññā}
\index{vipassanā}
\index{ñāṇa}
\index{nirvāṇa}
\index{nibbāna}
\index{permanency}
%\index{vipallāsa}
%\index{personality}
%\index{sakkāya}
%\index{diṭṭhi}
% sortedCanonList.txt
\index{aādiparokkhāyañca}
\index{sammāyojitajālavāta}
\index{ṃsati}
\index{ḷukhappa}
\index{homaidaṃ}
\index{sumanosmīti}
\index{sāmākanīvāre}
\index{vīriyārambhassa}
\index{jeṭṭhasissa}
\index{ñattikammavācāpi}
\index{ñattikammaṃ}
\index{ārammaṇamariyādā}
\index{aāgamo}
\begingroup
\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

> To 2. Minimal version (Pāḷi language only)

This is a list of 41 letter groups used in the alphabet.

```
% run: lualatex or xelatex typeset-paliminimal.tex
% Alphabet has 41 elements.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newenvironment{alphabet}{\begin{tabular}{*{16}{l}}}{\end{tabular}}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2in}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm
\setmainfont{Code2000}

\begin{document}
\section{Paliminimal}
\subsection{Alphabet}
\begin{alphabet}
a\,A\\
ā\,Ā\\
i\,I\\
ī\,Ī\\
u\,U\\
ū\,Ū\\
e\,E\\
o\,O\\
k\,K\\
kh\,Kh\,KH\\
g\,G\\
gh\,Gh\,GH\\
ṅ\,Ṅ & ɲ\,Ɲ\\
c\,C\\
ch\,Ch\,CH\\
j\,J\\
jh\,Jh\,JH\\
ñ\,Ñ\\
ṭ\,Ṭ & ʈ\,Ʈ\\
ṭh\,Ṭh\,ṬH\\
ḍ\,Ḍ & ɖ\,Ɖ\\
ḍh\,Ḍh\,ḌH\\
ṇ\,Ṇ & ɳ\,ɳ\\
t\,T\\
th\,Th\,TH\\
d\,D\\
dh\,Dh\,DH\\
n\,N\\
p\,P\\
ph\,Ph\,PH\\
b\,B\\
bh\,Bh\,BH\\
m\,M\\
y\,Y\\
r\,R\\
l\,L\\
v\,V\\
s\,S\\
h\,H\\
ḷ\,Ḷ & ɭ\,ɭ\\
ṃ\,Ṃ & ŋ\,Ŋ & ɱ\,ɱ
\end{alphabet}
\subsection{Ligatures}
\begin{flushleft}
`ß' is sorted like `s\,s', but \emph{after} it in otherwise equal words.
\end{flushleft}
\subsection{Upper-/lowercase words}
Capitalized or uppercase words are sorted \emph{before} otherwise equal lowercase words.
\subsection{Special characters}
The order of special characters and letters is:
\begin{flushleft}
?\hspace{4mm}!\hspace{4mm}.\hspace{4mm}letters\hspace{4mm}-\hspace{4mm}'
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 2, minimal version]

> Usage

Please download these two files:

```
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/utf8.pl-paliminimal.in.xdy
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/utf8.pl-paliminimal.in-test.xdy
```

We run these three lines (the terms are identical to those used in the first example for comparison reasons):

```
lualatex mal-paliminimal.tex
xindy -M texindy -M utf8.pl-paliminimal.in-test -M bonus mal-paliminimal.idx
lualatex mal-paliminimal.tex
```

If you would like to check out the vector versions, the PDF files can be downloaded as follows:

```
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/typeset-paliminimal.pdf
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/pi/mal-paliminimal.pdf
```

This is the content of the second TeX file and a preview of both versions is enclosed. The general version can be seen on left, the minimal version is the column of words on right.

```
% run: lualatex or xelatex mal-paliminimal.tex
% uncomment line 9 or 10, respectively
%
%lualatex mal-paliminimal.tex
%xindy -M texindy -M utf8.pl-paliminimal.in-test -M bonus mal-paliminimal.idx
%lualatex mal-paliminimal.tex
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra} % for lualatex engine
%\usepackage{xltxtra} % for xelatex engine
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bonus.xdy}
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n  \textbf{" :close-head "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Regular text.
\index{pāḷi}
\index{ānāpānasati}
\index{saṃsāra}
\index{ñāṇavimutti}
% Pali Buddhist Dictionary
\index{insight}
\index{paññā}
\index{vipassanā}
\index{ñāṇa}
\index{nirvāṇa}
\index{nibbāna}
\index{permanency}
%\index{vipallāsa}
%\index{personality}
%\index{sakkāya}
%\index{diṭṭhi}
% sortedCanonList.txt
\index{aādiparokkhāyañca}
\index{sammāyojitajālavāta}
\index{ṃsati}
\index{ḷukhappa}
\index{homaidaṃ}
\index{sumanosmīti}
\index{sāmākanīvāre}
\index{vīriyārambhassa}
\index{jeṭṭhasissa}
\index{ñattikammavācāpi}
\index{ñattikammaṃ}
\index{ārammaṇamariyādā}
\index{aāgamo}
\begingroup
\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a preview of indices, both versions (general version on left, minimal version on right)]

Comment: Could you please update the links to get the files `utf8.pl-paliminimal.in.xdy` and `utf8.pl-paliminimal.in-test.xdy`?

Comment: @tatojo Temporary solution. My files can be downloaded here, for now: https://uloz.to/!IAZUHKrGZgOW/malipivo-tex-sx-tar

Answer (score 9):

Gotcha!

So in the preamble of our `.tex` source, we say

```
\usepackage{index}
\newindex{general}{general-idx}{general-ind}{General Index}
```

In the text, we define the index entries in this fashion:

```
\index[general]{\=an\=ap\=anasati}
\index[general]{sa\d{m}s\=ara}
\index[general]{\~n\=a\d{n}avimutti}
```

When we compile the `.tex` document, we will get our `book.main.general-idx` file, which we have to process with `xindy`.

The main problem is that `texindy` loads many `.xdy` modules before it gets to our custom `style1.xdy`.

We have to invoke `xindy` directly, with an extended `style1.xdy`, that only defines what we need to be defined.

So I opened the modules (`/usr/share/xindy/...`) which `texindy` walks through as reported in its output,

```
Opening logfile "/dev/null" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "/tmp/1DxWUsIHQG"...
Loading module "lang/english/latin9-lang.xdy"...
Loading module "lang/english/latin9.xdy"...
Finished loading module "lang/english/latin9.xdy".
Finished loading module "lang/english/latin9-lang.xdy".
Loading module "tex/inputenc/latin.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex/inputenc/latin.xdy".
Loading module "texindy.xdy"...
Loading module "numeric-sort.xdy"...
Finished loading module "numeric-sort.xdy".
Loading module "latex.xdy"...
Loading module "tex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex.xdy".
Finished loading module "latex.xdy".
Loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy".
Loading module "makeindex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "makeindex.xdy".
Loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy".
Finished loading module "texindy.xdy".
Loading module "page-ranges.xdy"...
Finished loading module "page-ranges.xdy".
Loading module "word-order.xdy"...
Finished loading module "word-order.xdy".
Loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy"...
WARNING: define-letter-group: prefix "�" now maps to letter group "Þ"
Finished loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy".
Loading module "book-order.xdy"...
Finished loading module "book-order.xdy".
Finished loading module "/tmp/1DxWUsIHQG".
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)

Reading raw-index "/tmp/4o3huWTPhU"...
Finished reading raw-index.

Processing index... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]
Finished processing index.

Writing markup... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]
Markup written into file "book.main.general-ind".
```

And copied the necessary parts to `style1.xdy`, extending the definitions for the Pali letters where necessary. In the file below, the latin alpabet is extended with the letters ā, ī, ṃ, ñ. There's more in Pali, but this will do for now.

`style1.xdy`:

```lisp
;; xindy style file for an index with extended alphabet

(define-attributes (("default" "textbf" "textit" "hyperpage")))

;; "see" and "see also"

(define-crossref-class "see")
(markup-crossref-list :class "see" :open "\see{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")
(define-crossref-class "seealso")
(markup-crossref-list :class "seealso" :open "\seealso{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(markup-crossref-layer-list :sep ", ")

(require "base/numeric-sort.xdy")

(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers"))
(define-location-class "roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-lowercase"))
(define-location-class "Roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-uppercase"))
(define-location-class "alpha-page-numbers"  ("alpha"))
(define-location-class "Alpha-page-numbers"  ("ALPHA"))

(define-location-class-order ("roman-page-numbers"
                  "Roman-page-numbers"
                  "arabic-page-numbers"
                  "alpha-page-numbers"
                  "Alpha-page-numbers"
                  "see"
                  "seealso"))

(require "lang/english/utf8.xdy")

(define-alphabet "latin-pali"
("a" "ā" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "ī" "j" "k" "l" "m" "ṃ" "n" "ñ" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"))
(define-letter-groups
("a" "ā" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "ī" "j" "k" "l" "m" "ṃ" "n" "ñ" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"))

;; =======================
;; merge rules
;; =======================

;; for the pali words

;; TODO: some variations of the TeX accent markups could be combined using an :eregexp instead of :string replacements

(merge-rule "\=a" "ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\={a}" "ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\=A" "Ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\={A}" "Ā" :string)
(merge-rule "\={\i}" "ī" :string)
(merge-rule "\={\i }" "ī" :string)
(merge-rule "\d{m}" "ṃ" :string)
(merge-rule "\d {m}" "ṃ" :string)
(merge-rule "\~~n" "ñ" :string)
(merge-rule "\~~ n" "ñ" :string)

;; LaTeX and TeX conventions

(merge-rule "\\LaTeXe *" "LaTeX2e" :eregexp :again)
(merge-rule "\\BibTeX *" "BibTeX" :eregexp :again)
(merge-rule "\\AmSTeX *" "AmSTeX" :eregexp :again)
(merge-rule "\\AmSLaTeX *" "AmSLaTeX" :eregexp :again)
(merge-rule "\\XeT *" "XeT" :eregexp :again)

(require "base/tex.xdy")

(markup-locref :open "\textbf{" :close "}" :attr "textbf")
(markup-locref :open "\textit{" :close "}" :attr "textit")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}" :attr "hyperpage")

;; =======================
;; sort rules
;; =======================

;; list pali capitals under pali lowercase

(sort-rule "Ā" "ā")
(sort-rule "Ṃ" "ṃ")
(sort-rule "Ī" "ī")
(sort-rule "Ñ" "ñ")

;; list latin capitals under latin lowercase

(sort-rule "A" "a")
(sort-rule "B" "b")
(sort-rule "C" "c")
(sort-rule "D" "d")
(sort-rule "E" "e")
(sort-rule "F" "f")
(sort-rule "G" "g")
(sort-rule "H" "h")
(sort-rule "I" "i")
(sort-rule "J" "j")
(sort-rule "K" "k")
(sort-rule "L" "l")
(sort-rule "M" "m")
(sort-rule "N" "n")
(sort-rule "O" "o")
(sort-rule "P" "p")
(sort-rule "Q" "q")
(sort-rule "R" "r")
(sort-rule "S" "s")
(sort-rule "T" "t")
(sort-rule "U" "u")
(sort-rule "V" "v")
(sort-rule "W" "w")
(sort-rule "X" "x")
(sort-rule "Y" "y")
(sort-rule "Z" "z")

;; ======================
;; markup rules
;; ======================

(require "base/page-ranges.xdy")

(markup-index :open
"\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }
"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)

(markup-locclass-list :open ", " :sep ", ")
(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")

;; letter group markup

(markup-letter-group-list :sep "~n~n  \indexspace~n")

(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n  \lettergroupDefault{" :close-head "}" :group "default")
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n  \lettergroup{" :close-head "}")
```

If we now invoke `xindy` with

```
xindy -I latex -o book.main.general-ind -M style1 book.main.general-idx
```

We will get the `ind` file as below, with the extra lettergroups, which we can use with `\printindex[general]` in the appropriate place in the `.tex` document.

```
  \lettergroup{a}
  \item abiding, \hyperpage{33}
  \item absorption
    \subitem in daily activities, \hyperpage{132}
  \item accomplishments
    \subitem worldly, \hyperpage{66}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ā}
  \item \=acariya, \hyperpage{96}
  \item \=Al\=ara K\=al\=ama, \hyperpage{51}

  \indexspace

...

  \lettergroup{n}
  \item names, \hyperpage{21}, \hyperpage{23}, \hyperpage{183}
  \item nature
    \subitem existing according to, \hyperpage{69}
  \item nibb\=ana, \hyperpage{32}, \hyperpage{33}
    \subitem causes of, \hyperpage{76}
    \subitem meaning of, \hyperpage{54}
  \item nimitta, \hyperpage{41}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ñ}
  \item \~n\=ayapa\d {t}ipanno
    \subitem those who practice for realisation of the path, \hyperpage{58}

...
```

May this be for the happiness of many TeXnicians.